# Dynamic and Explicit Generic Interface Implementation

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, explicit-interface

I've learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11626335/738851) that dynamic variables cannot access methods on interfaces they explicitly implement. Is there an easy way to invoke the interface methods when I don't know the type parameter `T` at compile time?

```
interface I<T>
{
    void Method1(T t);
}

class C<T> : I<T>   
{   
    void I<T>.Method1(T t) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}

static void DoMethod1<T>(I<T> i, T t)
{
    i.Method1(t);
}

void Main()
{
    I<int> i = new C<int>();
    dynamic x = i;
    DoMethod1(x, 1);              //This works
    ((I<int>)x).Method1(2);       //As does this
    x.Method1(3);                 //This does not
}
```

I don't know the type parameter `T`, so (as far as I know) I can't cast my dynamic variable `x`. I have lots of methods in the interface, so don't really want to create corresponding `DoXXX()` pass through methods.

Edit: Note that I don't control and cannot change `C` or `I`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via reflection:

```
I<int> i = new C<int>();
dynamic x = i; // you dont have to use dynamic. object will work as well.
var methodInfo = x.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GetMethod("Method1");
methodInfo.Invoke(x, new object[] { 3 });
```

Comment: I can probably do something with reflection, but the type `C` implements multiple generic interfaces, and there are various overloads of some of the methods, so it's not easy.