# Error with duck enumeration for IAsyncEnumerable in System.Interactive.Async

Tags: c#, .net, system.interactive

I wonder why this code for `IAsyncEnumerable<>`

```
dynamic duckAsyncEnumerable = new int[0].ToAsyncEnumerable();
var duckAsyncEnumerator = duckAsyncEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
```

raises an exception:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Same code for `IEnumerable<>` works fine.
Moreover inplementation for `IAsyncEnumerable<>` via reflection works fine too.
Reproduced in .NET and .NET Core.

This code needed for `IOutputFormatter` implementation that get source data as object and have to iterate through it.

[described example in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gDNF6q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `new int[0].ToAsyncEnumerable()` will return the (internal) type `AsyncIListEnumerableAdapter<int>`. This type implements among other things `IEnumerable<int>` so it has the method `IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()`. However, **it implements this method using explicit interface implementation.**

An interface method that is explicitly implemented is not available when you call through `dynamic` (it is private). To access the method you will have to cast the reference to the interface first as explained in this [answer to the question *Use explicit interface implementations with a dynamic object*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11626335/98607).

Comment: As I undastand there is no way to call explicit implementations in dynamic vars. In my case there is the only way to use reflection. Maby alternative implicit implementation for ToAsyncEnumerable is the option? Is it an issue for system.interactive? Especially when there is no non generic interface IAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: @Weerel: Why do you have to use reflection? You can use the `as` operator: `var asyncEnumerable = duckAsyncEnumerable as IAsyncEnumerable<int>;` and then proceed if `asyncEnumerable` isn't null. If you really want to use duck typing you can combine this with the `dynamic` approach. Using `dynamic` is mostly asking the compiler to generate reflection code on your behalf anyway.

Comment: The problem is I don't actually know type of `IAsyncEnumerable<?>`, `int` just an example. I get it as `object` with any underlying type. I understand that non reflection/dynamic way is preferable option.

Comment: @Weerel: Using `dynamic` is mostly compiler generated reflection which makes it easier to do but not more efficient. It will only resolve public members. You can write your own reflection code to resolve private members.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. An object have extension method `ToAsyncEnumerable` which returns `IAsyncEnumerable<object>`. Thus we can iterate over it:

```
public async Task Process(object source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.ToAsyncEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (await enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var item = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

One can create wrapper that takes `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and implements `IAsyncEnumerable<object>`. `Activator` creates that wrapper in extension method. Here is the implementation:

```
public class AsyncEnumerable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<object>
{
    private IAsyncEnumerable<T> _source;

    public AsyncEnumerable(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerator<T>(_source.GetEnumerator());
    }
}

public class AsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<object>
{
    private IAsyncEnumerator<T> _source;

    public AsyncEnumerator(IAsyncEnumerator<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public object Current => _source.Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _source.Dispose();
    }

    public async Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _source.MoveNext(cancellationToken);      
    }
}

public static class AsyncEnumerationExtensions
{
    public static IAsyncEnumerable<object> ToAsyncEnumerable(this object source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }
        else if (!source.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<>)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("IAsyncEnumerable<> expected", nameof(source));
        }            

        var dataType = source.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<>))
            .GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var collectionType = typeof(AsyncEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(dataType);

        return (IAsyncEnumerable<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(collectionType, source);
    }
}
```